# Load Silverlight combo-box with data from a Entity Model in Host ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, silverlight-5.0

I have a particular scenario which has defied all attempts I made at handling it. I have a Silverlight application hosted in an ASP.NET MVC application. This ASP.NET application has an ADO.NET Entity model that connects to a database.

A combo box on the Silverlight page has a combo box that should be loaded with data when the ASP.NET page that hosts the silverlight application loads. The data that it should contain should come from the data in the ASP.NET application that hosts the silverlight app.

I thought of putting the data in a session within the ASP.NEt app's controller action that returns the view that hosts the silverlight app, hoping I could load it in the Load method of the Silverlight app but Sessions do not exist in silverlight.

I have equally tried WCF, Data Services, WCF RIA Library, Domain Service Class and I kept getting an error like "An error occured while trying to download service info". Please what is the best way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Ok guys I have made some progress, I found some help at this link: .However the source code example link was broken. Please how do I add the System.Xml.Serialization.Serializer dll to Silverlight? It keeps telling me it was not built against Silverlight runtime. I have a silverlight project that does not have the .Web part to it. Besides that, where on my PC can I find silverlight GAC assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

Here I found some material through these links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/cc195a53-f596-43de-9d99-8d6a6ed1ced0/how-to-serialize-a-object-to-xml-in-silverlight

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f090ee80-4574-40e4-98c3-fd3049a3e4ec/how-to-deserilize-the-serialized-xml-into-it-original-form-of-object-?forum=silverlightnet

http://www.dotnetglobe.com/2011/07/passing-objects-between-aspnet-and.html

Grateful for this platform S.O.